# Unable to get object's properties when using async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using Node.js and mongoose, but this question is purely about the `async` `await` part. I wrote this code, and it works works.

```
router.get('/applications/:_id', async (req, res, next) => {
    var posting = await Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true}); // await here
    var seekers = await Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false});
    console.log(posting.applications) // no await here
    // ^^^ this will log the applications array.
    res.render('users/employer/applications', {
        user: req.user,
        title: 'Job applications',
        applications: posting.applications,
        seekers: await seekers,
    })
});
```

But if I do this:

```
router.get('/applications/:_id', async (req, res, next) => {
    var posting = Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true}); // remove await from here
    var seekers = Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false});

    console.log(await posting.applications); // add await here
    // ^^^ this will log undefined
    res.render('users/employer/applications', {
        user: req.user,
        title: 'Job applications',
        applications: await posting.applications,
        seekers: await seekers,
    })
});
```

I am unable to get print out the `posting.applications` array. (It's undefined).

But I am able to print out the whole object like this:

```
router.get('/applications/:_id', async (req, res, next) => {
    var posting = Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true});
    // ^^^ remove await from here
    var seekers = Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false});

    console.log(await posting); // add await here
    // ^^^ this will log the object
    console.log(await posting.applications); // this will log undefined
    res.render('users/employer/applications', {
        user: req.user,
        title: 'Job applications',
        applications: await posting.applications,
        seekers: await seekers,
    })
});
```

I thought that await stops the execution of the code until it's fulfilled. So Why am I unable to get the properties, if the object is there?

[Duplicate note] I am also checking this by sending the object to the view. It behaves the same way in the view as in the console.log. This is a simplified example.

Comment: I am also checking this by sending the object to the view. It behaves the same way in the view as in the console.log. This is a simplified example.

Comment: @Isaac - I don't think so, this appears to be primarily a confusion over how `await` is used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first example:

```
var posting = await Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true}); // await here
var seekers = await Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false});
```

you're awaiting the promise that `Posting.findOne` and `Account.find` return, and storing the *resolution values* of those promises in `posting` and `seekers`.

In your second example:

```
var posting = Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true}); // remove await from here
var seekers = Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false});

console.log(await posting.applications); // add await here
```

...you're storing *the promise objects themselves* in `posting` and `seekers`, and then getting the property `applications` from the promise in `posting`. Promises don't have a property called `applications` so `posting.applications` results in `undefined`. `await`ing a non-promise value returns the value itself, so `await posting.applications` gives you `undefined`.

In your third example:

```
var posting = Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true});
// ^^^ remove await from here
var seekers = Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false});

console.log(await posting); // add await here
```

...you're again storing the *promise* in `posting`, but then awaiting that promise when doing the log, so the *resolution value* goes into `console.log`. But `posting` still refers to the promise, not its result, so `posting.applications` is still `undefined`.

In that third example, you could do:

```
posting = await posting;
```

...but really, your first example is fine.

If you want the `Posting.findOne` and `Account.find` to overlap, though, you can use `Promise.all`:

```
var [posting, seekers] = await Promise.all([
    Posting.findOne({'_id': req.params._id, 'creatorId': req.user._id, 'visible': true}),
    Account.find({'accType': 'seeker', 'blocked': false})
]);
```

Comment: Ooooh ok. That makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: One more note. You forgot the closing paraphrase in your final example. I cannot edit it, because I'd need to change 6 characters ;)

Comment: @AlexIronside - Thanks, fixed.